# Работа с Git после смены компьютера

Tags: git, github

Делал проект с ноутбука, который сломался. Затем, пересел на новую машинку и стал работать уже с неё. Проект был перенесён с флешки. Теперь на новом ноуте не могу делать коммиты.

Ошибки:

> error: unable to read askpass response from 'c:\Users\DIGMA 1\Desktop\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\git\dist\askpass.sh'
> error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 66)
> fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such file or directory

Как вернуть возможность коммитов и сделать так, чтобы новый ноут стал основным для этого проекта?

Comment: Просто склонировать репозиторий не пробовали?

Comment: Попробовал. Те же самые ошибки.

Comment: Рассказывайте, как настроена авторизация.

Comment: Скорее всего кастомно. Потому что я даже а не понял, о чём вы. Я создал проект. Зарагистрировался на хабе. Проинициализировал его с помощью inint и связал с локальным через git remote add origin.

Comment: На каком-то этапе вы должны были указывать свой ключ ssh либо http токен для доступа к своему репозиторию на гитхаб.

Comment: Да, когда связывал локальный гит с github указывал https-токен, который ведёт на репозиторий гитхаба.

Comment: Когда связывал на новом компьютере или на старом?

Comment: репа настроена на авторизацию с использованием askpass, а запчасти остались на старом компе.  курите маны https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials/2.26.0

Comment: Я бы сделал так:
1. клон репозитория в новую папку
2. вставляете старые файлы и смотрите какие не нужно изменять
3. делаете коммит-пуш